# Shell generate random adjective clause

Tags: bash, shell

I want generate random directory name. But name must be adjective clause. Also, created name must not be created again. I have two arrays:

```
names=("phone" "book" "pencil" "bag" "bed")
adjectives=("good" "bad" "thin" "short")
```

and i want this:

```
randomdir 2
```

good book, thin pencil directories has been created

```
randomdir 3
```

bad pencil, good bag, good phone directories has been created

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: "created name must not be created again" - then you don't really want random... If the chance that a duplicate might occur is removed, then it's no longer a random process...

Comment: What if there are less not-already-created names than the number you request to create?